# Is possible sort jqgrid by groupHeaders?

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqgrid in my application. Here [jsfidle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5yqRn/5/)

I am able to sort grid by S.No, Asset, Date and Amount. Is possible to sort grid by Location? and shipping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess no. http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:groupingheadar Read the limitations here, I'm not sure if it is fixed in latest version or not.